# why Spark 2.2's ALS recommendation system just support Int type for userCol and itemCol?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, apache-spark-ml

[image: Spark code]

Why Spark 2.2's  ALS Recommendation System support only Int type for userCol and itemCol?